# Pass value to parent controller when dismiss the controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I want to send data to parentviewcontroller but the following code crashes. Give me the solution

```
Post *vc;
vc.abc =@"Comment Conttroller";
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here, Post is the controller name from where I am calling the `presentViewController:animated:completion` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vc` doesn't seem to be initialized.

You can probably do this,

```
vc = (Post *)self.parentViewController;
vc.abc = @"Comment Conttroller";
[vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Since the view controller you want to affect is the `parentViewController`, you should be able to cast and set the `abc` property.

Answer (score 21):

Put this in your parent controller in `viewDidLoad`

```
// get register to fetch notification  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(yourNotificationHandler:)
                                      name:@"MODELVIEW DISMISS" object:nil];
// --> Now create method in parent class as;
// Now create yourNotificationHandler: like this in parent class
-(void)yourNotificationHandler:(NSNotification *)notice{
    NSString *str = [notice object];
}
```

Put following to your child class where

```
-(void)dissmissModelView{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"DismissModalviewController");

    //raise notification about dismiss 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
          postNotificationName:@"MODELVIEW DISMISS" 
                        object:@"Whatever you want to send to parent class"];  
}
```

as soon as model view get dismiss **yourNotificationHandler** get executed and whatever you pass as an objet will get fetch in your parent class. Please ask if still need some clarification.

Comment: really it worked like a miracle. Thanks a lot for this pretty code snippet. I am able to send values from child controllers to their respective parent controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Take this in .h file in **ParentViewController**

```
NSString *strABC;
```

Make below function in **ParentViewController**

```
-(void)setString:(NSString *)strEntered{
    strABC=strEntered;
}
```

Now In Post view controller do like this:

```
ParentViewController *objSecond = 
  [[ParentViewController] initwithNibName:@"parentView.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setString:@"Comment Controller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In **secondViewController** `viewWillAppear` method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      lblUserInput.text = strABC;
}
```

#### Please check spelling mistakes as I've hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using `UINavigationContoller` then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = 
  [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setUserInput:txtUserInput.text];
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to pass data when we are dismissing view. It shows how to pass when are push a new controller.

Comment: Its pushing parent view controller. This is not the right answer.